# How do I limit the maximum width of a text field?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple html page with just one text field and a button.

[image]

However, the text field is so wide.  How can I limit the maximum width (visual length not character number) to like 200px?
If possible without Javascript and if possible, the width should be kept at 100%. I played with maxlength and size but without success.

https://jsfiddle.net/Smolo/udh9s6j2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">


<div class='col-sm-12'><form action='' method='post'>
    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' class='form-control' required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Reset</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS `max-width` should do the trick.

**Explanation:** CSS's `max-width` makes sure that the width of the target element does not exceed 200px (even with `width:100%` set), i.e. the actual width of the element in your case will evaluate to either 100% or 200px, whichever is smaller.

```css
.form-control {
  max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">


<div class='col-sm-12'><form action='' method='post'>
    <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' class='form-control' required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Reset</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form></div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've decided to use an inline style='max-width:200px' to apply the style just for that element.